# start emulator failed (black screen) after build AOSP

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

After build Android Open Source Project on Mac 10.14, i try to run it on emulator. Here's the commands:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_x86_64-eng
emulator
```

after one hour, i still stuck in black screen, with the following details:

```
emulator: WARNING: system partition size adjusted to match image file (2560 MB > 200 MB)

emulator: WARNING: data partition size adjusted to match image file (3000 MB > 200 MB)

emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: ### WARNING: /etc/localtime does not point to /usr/share/zoneinfo/, can't determine zoneinfo timezone name
```